# Create a document and set the date - Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date, mongoose

I'm trying to create a document in mongo with a field date: Date.

When I post to API, the document created has a different time that I set, as follows:

```
{
"serialnumber": "1234567",
"date": "2019-08-30T10:32"
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "troubles": [],
    "_id": "5c35e9c8e726822a243936a9",
    "serialnumber": "1234567",
    "date": "2019-08-30T13:32:00.000Z",
    "updated": "2019-01-09T12:32:08.996Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

My mongoose Schema:

```
var MeasurementSchema = new Schema({
    serialnumber: String,
    date: Date
......
```

As we saw, I wrote 'T10:32', but, the time of parameter 'date' results in 12:32.

Any tips?

Comment: I't because of timezone. You have to check if timezone settings are the same on all of your devices

Comment: i already checked this, the timezone from my computer (local server) is 'America/DeNoronha

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB stores times in UTC by default, and will convert any local time representations into this form.

Applications that must operate or report on some unmodified local time value may store the time zone alongside the UTC timestamp, and compute the original local time in their application logic.

**Example**

In the MongoDB shell, you can store both the current date and the current client’s offset from UTC.

```
var now = new Date();
db.data.save( { date: now,
                offset: now.getTimezoneOffset() } );
```

You can reconstruct the original local time by applying the saved offset:

```
var record = db.data.findOne();
var localNow = new Date( record.date.getTime() -  ( record.offset * 60000 ) );
```

Comment: How this could help me?

Comment: Moment allow you to save Date and time with or without local time / UTC time. You can manipulate the results if needed from database as you wish.

Comment: Understood. So, the answer to this problem is create an middleware pre 'save' and use moment there?

Comment: Yes. you are correct. you can save the date into UTC datetime variable & then save the data to database.

Comment: I tried, but without success. When i save the date, the variable returns to the default timezone

Comment: i had completely changed my answer. Hope this will help you.